Converting and using a class component with functions to a functional component in React?
For context, I'm trying to make a project using the html canvas in React. I am trying to replace the class components with functional components for uniformity and avoiding mixing of class and functional components. The example below should simply move a blue rectangle from left to right.
I am convinced the file paths are correct, and my canvas and context variables are correctly initialised (code provided a bit later). However I'm a bit lost on how to proceed refactoring the code to make it behave the same as the class component.
This is the actual class and its usage (in vanilla javascript):
class Bar {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
  }
  update(){
    this.x++;
  }
  draw(context){
    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
  }
}

Usage:
const bar1 = new Bar(10, 10, 100, 200, "blue");
function animate(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  bar1.draw(ctx);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();

This is my attempt at mimicking the functionality. First, the Bar functional component:
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Bar = ({initialX, initialY, initialWidth, initialHeight, initialColor}) => {
    const [x, setX] = useState(initialX);
    const [y, setY] = useState(initialY);
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(initialWidth);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(initialHeight);
    const [color, setColor] = useState(initialColor);

    const update = () => {
        const newX = x + 1;
        setX(newX);
    }

    const draw = (context) => {
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    );
};

export default Bar;

And this is where the Bar component should be used, but I'm somewhat lost on how to "use" it. Do I just use it as a function? Render it as <Bar/> and provide props? Assign <Bar/> to a variable bar and use the draw() function from that?
import Bar from "../components/Bar.jsx";

const Visualiser = () => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    const animate = () => {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    animate();
};

export default Visualiser;

Would appreciate any guidance on how to go about this!

In a functional component you can use useRef to create a reference to the canvas, and then start the animation loop in a useEffect. The args for your boxes don't need to be in state.
const bars = [
  {
    x: 5,
    y: 5,
    width: 10,
    height: 10,
    color: '#000',
  },
  ...
]


const Canvas = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null); // use this to reference the canvas

  const update = (bar) => {
    bar.x += 1
  };

  const draw = (context, bars) => {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    boxes.forEach((bar) => {
      update(bar)
      context.fillStyle = bar.color;
      context.fillRect(bar.x, bar.y, bar.width, bar.height)
    })
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    let animationFrameId;

    const render = () => {
      draw(context, bars);
      // requestAnimationFrame will start the loop and run the render
      // function at the frame rate (usually 60fps)
      animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };
    
    render();

    return () => {
      // This will cancel the loop when this component unmounts
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={500} height={500} />
    </div>
  );
};


So if I have to create 100 bars in my "main" canvas, that means 100 canvas elements as well?

No. Use JS to render all your elements into this canvas. An HTML canvas can't have decedents. If you want to have a declarative structure consider using a library like Pixi.js.

I have edited my original question to include my canvas element which you rightly pointed out wasn't in the Bar component.
Essentially, I just want to abstract away a Bar component for modularity purposes.
But I don't want to use a class-based component for typical reasons (React-way, mixing of components, etc...).

You edited my post, not your original. Class vs function based components doesn't matter here because you can't nest a react component inside a canvas like you can for other DOM elements. i.e. <canvas><Bar /></canvas> is not valid. I'll edit my post based on your comments, but again it can be done declaratively.

*can't be done declaratively. Edit done, see if that helps.
